# Adding two numbers JS

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to add two numbers from range 10-99,for example:

```
Input:16
Output:1+6=7
Input:99
Output:18
```

```js
function digital_root(n) {
  var z = n.toString().length;
  if (z == 2) {
    var x = z[0] + z[1]
    return x;
  }
}

console.log( digital_root(16) );
```

Output from this code is NaN.What should I correct?

Comment: `z` is a number here, not a list or a string. So you are essentialy doing `undefined + undefined` which correctly outputs `NaN`

Comment: should it be `n[0]` and `n[1]` ?

Comment: don't use `.length` there.

Comment: @MarkC. `n` is `number`

Comment: @MarkC. `n` needs to be cast to String before using the brackets

Comment: I don't want to use libraries :) So in this if i should convert it to a string again?

Comment: @TemaniAfif, did you really say that?

Comment: @Ivan yes, better say it in the comment before someone really provde a jQuery solution as an answer :p

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```js
function digital_root(n) {
  var z = n.toString();
  //use length here
  if (z.length == 2) {
    //convert to int
    var x = parseInt(z[0]) + parseInt(z[1]);
    return x;
  } else {
    return "not possible!";
  }
}

console.log( digital_root(16) );
console.log( digital_root(99) );
console.log( digital_root(999) );
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) to split the string in half and add the two using [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) to convert to a number.

```
const sum = (s) => (''+s).split('').reduce((a,b) => parseInt(a)+parseInt(b))
       ↑             ↑        ↑         ↑
      our          coerce   split      sum
    function     to string  in two     both
```

Here a test :

```js
const sum = (s) => (''+s).split('').reduce((a,b) => parseInt(a)+parseInt(b))

console.log(sum(12))
```

Comment: Would you care to explain why you downvoted? Without a comment you're vote has no way of improving my answer.

Comment: @GuillaumeGeorges, thank you for the feedback, I have edited my answer.

Comment: I didnt vote down but the readability of your code is not optimal IMHO.

Comment: @CristianS. yes, it is quite condensed but for a function that short there is no need to break it down even further. Downvoting without a comment is nonsense.

Answer (score 1):

There are several approaches to sum digits of a number. You can convert it to a string but IDK if thats neccesary at all.  You can do it with numerical operations.

```js
var input = 2568,
    sum = 0;

while (input) {
    sum += input % 10;
    input = Math.floor(input / 10);
}

console.log(sum);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a fun short way to do it:

```
const number = 99
const temp = number.toString().split('')
const res = temp.reduce((a, c) => a + parseInt(c), 0) // 18
```

1.) Convert number to string

2.) Separate into individual numbers

3.) Use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to sum the numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Your way would be the iterational way to solve this problem, but you can also use a recursive way.

### Iterative solution (Imperative)

1. `n.toString()` Create String from number.
2. `.split("")` split string into chars.
3. `.reduce(callback, startValue)` reduces an array to a single value by applying the callback function to every element and updating the startValue.
4. `(s, d) => s + parseInt(d)` callback function which parses the element to an integer and adds it to `s` (the startValue).
5. `0` startValue.

### Recursive solution (Functional)

1. `condition?then:else` short-hand if notation.
2. `n<10` only one digit => just return it.
3. `n%10` the last digit of the current number (1234%10 = 4).
4. `digital_root_recurse(...)` call the function recursivly.
5. `Math.floor(n / 10)` Divide by 10 => shift dcimal point to left (1234 => 123)
6. `... + ...` add the last digit and the return value (digital root) of `n/10` (1234 => 4 + root(123)).

```js
function digital_root_string(n) {
  return n.toString().split("").reduce((s, d) => s + parseInt(d), 0);
}

function digital_root_recurse(n) {
  return n < 10 ? n : n % 10 + digital_root_recurse(Math.floor(n / 10));
}

console.log(digital_root_string(16));
console.log(digital_root_string(99));
console.log(digital_root_recurse(16));
console.log(digital_root_recurse(99));
```

Comment: What does applicative mean in this context?

Comment: Sorry, it's an translation mistake of me. It has to be functional

Comment: Ah, was just curious! :)

Answer (score 0):

The issue in your code is that you stored the length of `n` into `z`. The length is an integer, so both `z[0]` and `[1]` are undefined. The solution is to store the string into another variable and use that instead of `z`.

```js
function digital_root(n) {
  n = n.toString();
  var l = n.length;
  if (l === 2) {
    return parseInt(n[0], 10) + parseInt(n[1], 10);
  }
}

console.log( digital_root(16) );
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `var x =  parseInt(n/10) + (n%10);` and it will work for you.

```js
function digital_root(n) {
  var z = n.toString().length;
  if (z == 2) {
    var x =  parseInt(n/10) + (n%10);
    return x;
  }
}

console.log( digital_root(16) );
console.log( digital_root(99) );
console.log( digital_root(62) );
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert input to string, split it, convert each item back to number and sum them all:

```
function digital_root(n) {
    return String(n).split('').map(Number).reduce((a,b) => a + b)
}

const result = digital_root(99);

console.log(result);
```